# How do I install OpsView?

Tags: 10.04, installation

Trying to install opsview onto lucid. However, I'm not sure of the exact commands to run after altering the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. What commands are necessary after that?

Answer (score 2):

If you have already added the repository and GPG key.Skip to **step-2** and execute the commands in your terminal to install opsview,

**Adding repository:**
**Step-1:**

- Edit sources.list to add the repository

  `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`
- Add the below line to your sources.list file,

  ```
      deb http://downloads.opsera.com/opsview-community/latest/apt lucid main
  ```
- Now to add the GPG keys,execute the following commands in your terminal,

  `sudo gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv-key 77CB2CF6`
  `sudo gpg --export --armor 77CB2CF6 | sudo apt-key add -`

**Installing opsview:**
**Step-2:**

- To install opsview type the following in your terminal,

  `sudo apt-get update`
  `sudo apt-get install opsview`

**Note:**

- For more information see this **[page](http://www.craigertech.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=27:opsview-install-on-ubuntu-1004&catid=7:linux&Itemid=8)**.

Answer (score 1):

For Opsview community edition:

[Add the appropriate repository](http://docs.opsview.com/doku.php?id=opsview%3aapt). AFAIK only LTS versions are supported. For Lucid 10.04 this would be:

```
deb http://downloads.opsera.com/opsview-community/latest/apt lucid main
```

Import the GPG key for this repo:

```
sudo gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv-key 77CB2CF6
sudo gpg --export --armor 77CB2CF6 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then you should be able to install opsview from CLI as karthick87 already pointed out. You can also use Synaptic for both, updating your sources list, and installation in case you are more compfortable using a GUI.

For Opsview enterprise edition please ask for support from [Opsera](http://www.opsera.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The answers listed here are no longer relevant if you're looking to utilize the new version of opsview labeled 'opsview-core'.

Opsview core **removes** SNMP Trap processing, distributed monitoring capabilities, master-slave monitoring capabilities, and more.

For information on how to upgrade, please see the opsview wiki article here: http://docs.opsview.com/doku.php?id=opsview-core:upgrading:upgradetocore

For information on how to install the newest opsview-core:
http://www.opsview.com/technology/downloads/opsview-core

You have 3 options - VM appliance image, Server installation, or EC2-image installation.

- [Virtual Appliance instructions](http://www.opsview.com/technology/guides-help/opsview-installation/opsview-core-vm)
- [Linux Server Installation Video](http://player.vimeo.com/video/41082051?width=531&height=300&iframe=true)
- [Amazon EC2 installation tutorial](http://player.vimeo.com/video/44813253?width=531&height=300&iframe=true)